# How can I get the parameter estimate of sill of variograms in the spatial correlation structure in linear mixed effect model?

Tags: lme4-nlme

I want to test the effects of x on y using linear mixed effect model with nlme package, in which the spatial correlation structure in residuals needs to be considered.

```
lme(y~x,random = ~1|Site,corr = corSpatial(form =~(LAT + LON), type ="exponential", nugget = T),data=data)
```

```
Output:
Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | Study
        (Intercept)  Residual
StdDev:   0.1251076 0.3226046

Correlation Structure: Exponential spatial correlation
 Formula: ~(LAT + LON) | Study 
 Parameter estimate(s):
      range      nugget 
0.001270257 0.757162137 
Fixed effects: y ~ x 
                 Value  Std.Error  DF  t-value p-value
(Intercept) 0.21069542 0.02895637 148 7.276307       0
x                0.07021087 0.01655359 148 4.241429       0
 Correlation: 
            (Intr)
x -0.146

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
       Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
-3.4111180 -0.6064486 -0.0992510  0.3887665  2.6713372 

Number of Observations: 205
Number of Groups: 56
```

Only range and nugget were shown in the output of linear mixed effect model when I considered the spatial correlation structure. Why is the other parameter 'sill' of variogram not shown?

Comment: "Not shown" by what software?  You need to show us what you're doing before we have any hope of helping.

Comment: Your output states this is the "correlation" structure: that tells you what the sill is.